# Determine whether the given is rational functions or rational equation

Tags: rational-functions

Is a rational function or a rational equation or none of these?

- 1.) $y=5x³-2x+1$
- 2.) $g(x)=7x³-4√x+1/x²+3$

Hope you'll help me thanks

Comment: Well they certainly don't look like equations to me ... What are your own thought about this question?

Answer (score 0):

A rational function is defined as $f(x) = \frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$ for any polynomials $P$ and $Q$ (constant polynomials as well). Thus, we see that (1) $\boxed{\text{is a rational function}}$ with $P(x) = 5x^3-2x+1$ and $Q(x) = 1$. We also see that (2) $\boxed{\text{is not a rational function}}$ because it contains square roots.